# docker-compose, dockerfile and vars to select the image from dockerhub or local

Tags: docker, variables, docker-compose, dockerfile, environment-variables

I have a working docker configuration with

- one dockercompose file
- for some service a dockerfile with extras

What i like to achive is that a i can pull latest images form dockerhub or (When they are not ok), use my own local dockerhub images on localhost:5000 (the part is already working)

I like to use a .env var for this where a variable (TAG) is empty (use the dockerhub image) or filled with a prefix in front of the image so that the local image is pulled
I have a sort of way of doing this , and like to check if this is gonna work!
I only described the parts that are relevant for this purpose

Can somebody, a pro,  check this for me, i am an amateur :-)

### env file (dynamic written by bash script)

TAG=localhost:5000/
(or TAG is empty and then the dockerhub store is used and the default name of the image)

### dockercompose

service_a:      (dockerfile is used, see dockerfile env/arg)
build: /home/pi/pvkmenu/services/homer/.

service_b:
image: "${TAG}b4bz/homer:latest"

### dockerfile for service a

ARG TAG
ENV envTAG=$TAG
FROM ${envTAG}b4bz/homer:latest

CMD
docker-compose up  (same folder as .env)

(if .env is on another place / has another name, then)
docker-compose --env-file ./config/.env.dev config

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you try to elaborate a bit, please? Look into [how to ask  a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details.

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no option in docker-compose to say to pull image from dockerHub or build locally based on a condition